# API Project local network

Tags: .net, iis, web, asp.net-web-api

A coworker and i are working developing different WEB API's that communicates one to other, or Clients Apps to (APIs). The thing is, my Client App should communicate to his Web API App (or his Client App to my Web API App) from his computer to my Computer. The client may be a console, or a mvc project or whatever, thats not important.

It is possible to allow a running (debugging) WEB API Project to be reached by my partner which is in the same network?

For example, if i run my web api application (of course im using Visual Studio) it will launch the project and open my web navigator, for example: "localhost:10923/api/exampleApiController", so, my partner should be able to have access to it (this time with my ip): "10.10.78.56:10923/api/exampleApiController" right?

But is not working =/, i am not even able to access to it on my local computer by using my own IP instead of "localhost".

Any idea or suggestion?, we want to simulate a real client-server interaction.

Comment: Create an application on your machine in IIS and map it to the project folder.you should be able to browse to it once set up. The other machine should ba able to get your IP:80 and hit your server. If not then check firewall setting.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach your partner's web app through his external IP address. If the web app is inside your local network, then use the internal IP address. If not, then there is a need of [port-forwarding](http://portforward.com/) to make the web app reachable online.

Comment: But i am using my internal IP address.

Comment: This is an external IP address: 10.10.78.56. Port 10923 should be forwarded.